# onresize does not work

Tags: javascript, onresize

I'm doing a responsive site then a I'm using:

```
window.addEventListener("resize", function(){
   if(window.innerWidth < 768){
      //execute some code
   }
   else{
      //execute some code
   }
});
```

When my navigator is at full width and click at the "Restore Down" button the window is resized to a width less then 768 the code inside of addEventListener("resize") doesn't work. These images below shows the condition of this "resize". My code works only when I resize the window using the pointer of the mouse.

[image]

[image]

Any solution for this situation?

Comment: It's working for me in Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/lharby/xx6eb7gb/

Comment: Thank you. The problem may be some framework that I'm using.

Comment: Hmmm, difficult to tell, if you can make a fiddle you can include other js files/frameworks if they are hosted somewhere (cdn etc).

Comment: Sorry, I can't =( I would like so much to do this but I can't show my code and it's hard to reproduce the problem because I'm using Drupal.

Comment: I wonder then if you are seeing another js error which is stopping the resize function running.

Comment: In my console there aew this errors:
 GET chrome-extension://boadgeojelhgndaghljhdicfkmllpafd/cast_sender.js net::ERR_FAILED
www-embed-player.js:166 GET chrome-extension://dliochdbjfkdbacpmhlcpmleaejidimm/cast_sender.js net::ERR_FAILED
www-embed-player.js:166 GET chrome-extension://hfaagokkkhdbgiakmmlclaapfelnkoah/cast_sender.js net::ERR_FAILED
www-embed-player.js:166

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**onresize** doesn't fire with **attachEvent** or **addEventListener**. you must attach your callback directly to **window.onresize**.

## syntax

> window.onresize = funcRef;

## example

```
window.onresize = resize;

function resize() {
    alert("resize event detected!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the window.**onresize** event.

```
window.onresize = function ResizeApp()
{
  if(window.innerWidth < 768)
  {
    //execute some code
  }
  else
  {
    //execute some code
  }
}
```